# Code not present inside namespace and class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0

I am learning C# and came across a sample code which are as follows :

**Shapes.cs**

```
using System;

public record Position(int X, int Y);

public record Size(int Width, int Height);

public abstract record Shape(Position Position, Size Size)
{
    public void Draw() => DisplayShape();

    protected virtual void DisplayShape()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Shape with {Position} and {Size}");
    }
}
```

**ConcreteShapes.cs**

```
using System;

public record Rectangle(Position Position, Size Size) : Shape(Position, Size)
{
    protected override void DisplayShape()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Rectangle at position {Position} with size {Size}");
    }
}

public record Ellipse(Position Position, Size Size) : Shape(Position, Size)
{
    protected override void DisplayShape()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Ellipse at position {Position} with size {Size}");
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
Rectangle r1 = new(new Position(33, 22), new Size(200, 100));
Rectangle r2 = r1 with { Position = new Position(100, 22) };
Ellipse e1 = new(new Position(122, 200), new Size(40, 20));

DisplayShapes(r1, r2, e1);

void DisplayShapes(params Shape[] shapes)
{
    foreach (var shape in shapes)
    {
        shape.Draw();
    }
}
```

**Project structure :**

[image]

**Question :**

When I build the project and run the the project with the below command :

```
dotnet run --project .\RecordsInheritance\RecordsInheritance.csproj
```

I am getting output which i.e. DisplayShapes method is getting called and output is displayed.
The C# code in Program.cs is not wrapped inside a namespace and a class and yet it is getting executed correctly like a javascript code.
Can someone explain me how this code is getting executed correctly as the code is not wrapped inside a class and there is no public static method as well ?

Comment: [Top level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new feature in Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6 SDK >

[Top Level Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements)

It is a simplified way to express the entry point of your applications.

In other words is a new way of writing the Program.cs class.

According to Microsoft

> Top-level statements enable you to avoid the extra ceremony required

when writing your entry point.

Answer (score 0):

Recent version of C# and .NET has few enhancements that you see:

- file scoped namespces, that allow to write

```
namespace MyProject;
// All below does not need braces and indentation, it goes to above namespace
public class ......
```

- due to that, template for console app could be simplified and now body of the file is just what would be places inside `Main` method, thus it gets executed and you don't need anthing execpt compiling code there

Further reading
[File scoped namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces)
[New Console App template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates)

Comment: file scoped namespaces have nothing to do with  Top Level Statements feature..... These are separate features altogether

Comment: Even futher he is not even specifying a namespace at all which means those artifacts are getting compiled under the default namespace